# When does a shell alias take effect?

Tags: shell, sh, posix, alias

I read the "Alias Substitution" section in the POSIX spec but cannot seem to figure this one out.

Consider these two scripts:

```
alias x="echo hello"
x
```

and

```
if true; then
    alias x="echo hello"
    x
fi
```

In the two shells I tested (dash and zsh), both have the same behaviour. The first script prints "hello" and the second script produces an error because `x` is not a command.

From these tests, it seems the alias goes into effect at the beginning of the next `complete_command` in the POSIX grammar. If this is the case where is it stated in the POSIX spec?

Comment: Aliases are not expanded in scripts by default.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams From what I could tell, this was not the behaviour in the two shells I tested (sh and zsh). I'm interested in the behaviour as it is defined in the POSIX spec.

Answer (score 0):

See the [POSIX specification for alias substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01).

Alias substitutions occur during parsing (or, at least, prior to evaluation). Because the entire `if` statement is one compound command that is parsed all at once, that means `x` undergoes alias substitution *before* the preceding `alias` command actually defines the alias, and could only be replaced by an alias that was defined on a complete command line *before* the `if` statement.

For example, consider the code

```
alias x="echo hello"
if true; then
    x
fi
```

After parsing, this is transformed to the code

```
alias x="echo hello"
if true; then
    echo hello
fi
```

and *that* is the code that actually gets executed.

Now consider

```
alias x="echo hello"
if true; then
    alias x="echo goodbye"
    x
fi
x
```

Again, at the time the `if` statement is parsed, `x` is defined as `echo hello`, not `echo goodbye`. *After* the `if` is parsed and executed, though, `x` has been redefined, so the above is equivalent to

```
alias x="echo hello"
if true; then
    alias x="echo goodbye"
    echo hello
fi
echo goodbye
```